# Synchronized and unsynchronized writers to HashMap - results not as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have come across code that does not properly synchronize access to a Map - however I analyzed the impact of the non-synchronized code and it is not as I expected.

Essentially the code has multiple writer threads that write to a HashMap perAccountMap_ this code is correctly synchronized.

However there is a section of code called by a separate thread which reads the Map and resets it:

```
// Unsynchronized code :( - called from a single thread - reads Map and resets it
    public static Map<PDKey, PData> copyAndClearPerAccountMap()
    {
        Map<PDKey, PData> copyMap = perAccountMap_;
        perAccountMap_ = new HashMap<PDKey, PData>();
        return copyMap;
    }
```

Now, I was able to independently validate the contents of the Map that was being copied above on some multi-core boxes.
Intuitively I would have expected the copyMap above to underestimate the entries in the Map - i.e. because it is not synchronized the other synchronized writer threads inserts to the Map will not necessarily be visible to this single thread that takes a copy of it.
However the reverse appears to be the case - the copy above appears to consistently have ca. 1% more entries.
I can fix the unsynchronized code, but I don't understand the results I observed.

Comment: I don't understand. You aren't copying a map, you are copying the reference. Can you rephrase the behavior you are seeing or post code that would reproduce it?

Comment: Sorry my bad - yes copying a reference of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best theory I can offer is that the writer threads are still writing into the original map for a short time after the change is made. This could especially happen if `perAccountMap_` is not volatile as the change made by the `copyAndClear` method would not be seen by the other threads immediately.

Comment: Yes that's plausible. Now the unsychronized thread kicks in every 15 mins (ScheduledExecutorService) creating a new Map, while the synchronized threads run many times a second. But wouldn't the new Map not have the writes to the original Map.

Comment: It wouldn't have the writes to the original map, however different writer threads could be writing to the original and the new maps at the same time.